# Creating own component based on TreeView (TTreeNode issue)

Tags: delphi, treeview, lazarus

just need o access to my custom TreeView with this:

```
MyTreeView1.Selected.MyOwnProperty := 'something';
```

So, all i want to do is make same component as TreeView is but + i need to add my own property to all of the TreeNodes of TreeView.

If I may ask again, can anybody explain me how to use "data property of TTreeNodes to point to an object"? Could anybody explain how to save some information to it (for example name and age) and how to get this information from selected TTreeNode?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

At least with XE, you can override the creation of tree nodes with a TTreeView using the [OnCreateNodeClass](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/ComCtrls.TTreeView.OnCreateNodeClass) property to create custom TTreeNodes.

For example:

```
type
  TMyTreeNode = class (TTreeNode)
  //
  end;

procedure TMyForm.OnCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  MyTreeView.OnCreateNodeClass := OnCreateNodeClass;
end;

procedure TMyForm.OnCreateNodeClass(Sender: TCustomTreeView; 
  var NodeClass: TTreeNodeClass);
begin
  NodeClass := TMyTreeNode;
end;
```

You can then subclass TTreeView to change Selected to return your tree node class.

Comment: In D2007 also, so has been available for a while

Comment: +1 Oh dear I am so out of date! `TTreeView<TNode: TTreeNode>` would still be great though, no need for casting.

Comment: Thanks for reply but I can't use it at design time. That's the main reason why am i writing here. But i'm not really sure if it is possible.

Comment: @Manny It's surely no fun to populate trees at design time. Take this opportunity to free yourself from that particular pain.

Comment: @Roddy It's there in D6 too. It's probably been there since the very first version of the class. This is a class I use a lot and thought I knew well!

Answer (score 1):

I usually use the data property of TTreeNodes to point to an object that contains the actual data that I'm working with.

That approach encourages separating your model from the GUI, which is a Good Thing.

Comment: Could you explain how to save some information to it (for example name and age) and how to get this information from selected TTreeNode via data property?

Answer (score 0):

Manny, if you want to access your custom property at design time you also need to program designtime support for this - custom property editor for Items property.